# How to run the MediaCodec Sample available at bigflake.com

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediarecorder

Bigflacke has sample code to illustrate how to use MediaCodec Api available in Android 4.3 onward. My question how to run this file to test this code. Is we need to create a new project and add this code which extending AndroidTestCase instead of Activity.

Here is the link to [bigflake.com](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)

I want to compress a high resolution video to low resolution. Any example or tutorial. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

for video resolution change you can use Intel INDE Media Pack, it has a nice samples set and tutorials how to build and run app: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-running-samples

[image]

It also allows live streaming through wowza services to youtube or other services, here is the tutorial: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-streaming-from-device-to-youtube